# Symfony 2: Static function [JMSTranslation]

Tags: symfony, static, translation

I'm currently working on a project that the previous developer integrated with JMSTranslationBundle.
At this moment, I've did some modification to the application, one of them was to turn the menu to be highly dynamic. (Basically, the user logic of the application have 3 layers and each layer have their own menu).

The menu are stored into the database and accessible through the doctrine entity. To display the label, I store into the DB the "label code" which is used by JMSTranslationBundle as a key to identify it. The desc is by default empty until setted into the translation file. (editable with the _trans route).

Into the documentation of JMS, it is mentionned that one can implement TranslationContainerInterface so when the compilation of the translation file (who are XLIFF file currently) are done, each class implementing this will be called to return a list of Message objects. Here's my issue:

The function to implement is static, meaning that when call, my model Menu (who handle to logic of fetching throught Doctrine repo) is not loaded via the service manager. This means that I do not receive the repository object (since it's loaded by service and pass through the controller):

```
public function __construct(MenuRepository $objMenuRepo)...
```

The definition of the function I implements is:

```
static function getTranslationMessages(){ ... }
```

My question is: how can I obtain the doctrine (either manager or repository) within that static function . (Since this will be only called on translation initial generation and not by the site itsef, performance is not an issue I worry about).

Also: If anyone have better alternative to propose (that wouldn't involved getting rid of this translation bundle, trust me, it would take quite an amount of time right now), I'm opened to hear them.

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

If some of you are interested, I had to use an alternative solution.

Although it doesn't answer the question on how to use a service within a static context, it will help those who ran into the same issue I had when attempting to implement with JMSTranslation.

To implement the solution (to extract translation key from the database), I had to use the JMS\TranslationBundle\Translation\ExtractorInterface.
I have implement it under this format:

```
class TranslationRepositoriesExtractor implements ExtractorInterface{
   //Loaded through the service container
   public function __construct(EntityRepository $objRepositoryNeeded);

   // Implementation of the interface ExtractorInterface.
   // Within this function, I've used the EntityRepository received in the 
   // constructor to fetch the list of keys that would be use for translating
   /**
   * @return \JMS\TranslationBundle\Model\Message[]
   */
   public function extract()
}
```

As you  can notice, the extract function return an array of \JMS\TranslationBundle\Model\Message. 
After implementing this function, you have to add your object as a service and make it recognizable by JMSTranslationBundle as an extractor. To do so:

```
 <!-- Replace the id of the service, the class path, the id of the argument and the alias 
      named you want by the value you need in your application -->
    <service id="idOrYourService" class="Path\Of\Class\TranslationRepositoriesExtractor">
        <argument type="service" id="repository.needed" />
        <tag name="jms_translation.extractor" alias="NameOfAlias" />
    </service>
```

The alias tag is used within JMSTranslationBundle to recognize your class as an extractor.

Finally, when generating the files, I had to had to enable the extractor. This can be done via the config, but in my case, was done manually through the command line

```
php app/console translation:extract --enable-extractor=NameOfAlias en
// NameOfAlias is the same name as the one defined in the tag of your service
```

I hope I didn't forget any step (if so, feel free to reply in a comment and I'll update the answer).

Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using this input, I ended up coding this version of the extractor.

```
<?php
namespace MyBundle\Service;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use JMS\TranslationBundle\Model\Message;
use JMS\TranslationBundle\Model\MessageCatalogue;
use JMS\TranslationBundle\Translation\ExtractorInterface;

/**
 * Extracts translatable strings from Doctrine entities
 *
 * @package MyBundle\Service
 */
class EntityTranslationExtractor implements ExtractorInterface
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    private $entityManager;

    /**
     * EntityTranslationExtractor constructor.
     *
     * @param EntityManager $entityManager
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    /**
     * @return MessageCatalogue
     */
    public function extract()
    {
        $messageCatalogue = new MessageCatalogue();

        // Sample portion of the extraction
        $translatableEntities = $this->entityManager->getRepository('MyBundle:MyEntity')->findAll();
        foreach ($translatableEntities as $entity) {
            $message = new Message($entity::class .'.'. $entity->getName(). '.name');
            $message->setDesc(ucwords($entity->getName()));
            $messageCatalogue->add($message);
        }

        return $messageCatalogue;
    }
}
```